# QB64 Open Com port causes data read error

Tags: input, port

There seems to be a fundamental problem with QB64 Open Com statement at least with my compiler. When I open the com port with OPEN "Com3: 9600,n,8,1,ds0,cs0,rs" FOR RANDOM AS #1 while knowing that there is data in the buffer and print EOF, LOC, LOF. It shows EOF=0 OK fine but LOC and LOF both show 0. If you then exercise a GET statement you get a "bad record length" because LOF=0. If I use OPEN FOR INPUT then I immediately get EOF=-1, LOF and LOC=0. If I then use INPUT# I get an input past end of file error because EOF was already -1.
I know that the buffer contains" Voltage = 1.2* "(no quotes) If I say continue upon the input past end of file error I actually get Part of the message.
Is there a fix for this com port problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you test the com port you will find Windows nicely blocks those ports:

```
REM test com port keyboard i/o
OPEN "COM3:9600,N,8,1,BIN,CS0,DS0" FOR RANDOM AS #1
DO
    IF LOC(1) THEN
        GET 1, , x
        PRINT CHR$(x);
    END IF
    x$ = INKEY$
    IF LEN(x$) THEN
        IF x$ = CHR$(27) THEN END
        x = ASC(x$)
        PUT 1, , x
    END IF
LOOP
END
```